# Execute 3 attribute class python

Tags: python-2.7, class

Here's my code

```
class Word:

    def motivation(self):
       return 'Dont Give up'
    def __call__(self, x):
       return 'love'
    def __call__(self, c):
       return 'hate'
    def dude(self):
       return 'dude'
    def brother(self):
       return 'brother'

word = Word()
```

with this code i must produce like this

```
>>> word.motivation.dude
'Dont Give Up Dude'
```

And must be like this too

```
>>> word.motivation.brother
'Dont Give Up Brother'
```

if i execute with this script, the output get error

```
AttributeError: 'Function' object has no attribute 'dude'
```

and

```
AttributeError: 'Function' object has no attribute 'brother'
```

Comment: Well python is right: your function called `motivation` does not have attributes such as `dude` or `brother`. They belong to Word objects. Like your word variable. You can write word.motivation(), word.motivation, word.dude and word.brother.

Comment: Soo , where i must write the script for word dude and word brother?

Comment: You want to type exactly `word.motivation.dude` and see: 'Dont Give Up Dude'? You can have that in the python interactive shell but such a construct seems pointless to me. Or is it OK to write something else, like word.motivation("dude")? Moreover, you wrote 'dude' in your script but want to see 'Dude' as output, does it mean the first letter must be turned into a capital?

Comment: Yeah, this is just sample for my training with python. `word.motivation.dude` and `word.motivation.brother` must be produce like the sample above. If i create a new `class` and than combine with `class Word` No change, still error.